# Merging 2 data frames with different number of rows based on a column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, concatenation

I have 2 dataframes:

1. A = col (Ids, a,b,c,d); size = 40*5
2. B = col (Ids,y,z); size =100*3

I need to get it as follows:
C = col (Ids,a,b,c,d,y,z) only where A.ids = B.ids

I tried merge and concat, but not reaching the right ans.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share a sample of your dataset and/or the code used ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that the columns merged have the same `dtype` and then use [**`pandas.merge`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge.html) :

```
C = A.merge(B, on="Ids") # how="inner" by default
```

Comment: Correct. I did not have the same data type for Ids in both the frames. hence was not able to merge.